# Scheme write a function that returns number of odd numbers in a list

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm having trouble writing a function in Scheme that returns the number of odd numbers in a list without using any assignment statements. I'm trying to use the predicate odd? as well. Any help/tips would be appreciated.

Ex: (odds '(1 2 3 4 5) // returns 3

Also, the list is of integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless if you use (R6RS?) Scheme or Racket, this will work for both:

```
(define (odds lst)
  (length (filter odd? lst)))

(define l '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
(odds l)
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, if no assignment statements can be used, you can still use the built-in procedures for this. In particular, [`count`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._count%29%29) will work nicely in Racket:

```
(define (odds lst)
  (count odd? lst))
```

... But I'm guessing that you're supposed to implement the solution from scratch. Some hints for finding the solution on your own, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (odds lst)
  (cond (<???>                 ; if the list is empty
         <???>)                ; then how many odd numbers are in it?
        ((odd? <???>)          ; if the first element is odd
         (<???> (odds <???>))) ; then add one and advance recursion
        (else                  ; otherwise
         (odds <???>))))       ; just advance the recursion
```

Anyway, it works as expected:

```
(odds '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

As low level as I can get it :

```
(define odds
  (lambda (lst) 
    (cond ((empty? lst) 0)
          ((not (= 0 (modulo (car lst) 2))) (+ 1 (odds (rest lst))))
          (else (odds (cdr lst))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one-liner

```
(define (odds L)
 (reduce + 0 (map (lambda (x) (if (odd? x) 1 0)) L)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that returns a function that counts anything based on a predicate:

```
(define (counter-for predicate)
  (define (counting list)
    (if (null? list)
        0
        (+ (if (predicate (car list)) 1 0)
           (counting (cdr list)))))
   counting))
```

which is used like:

```
(define odds (counter-for odd?))
```

**[MORE OPTIONS]** Here is a nice recursive solution

```
(define (odds list)
  (if (null? list)
      0
      (+ (if (odd? (car list)) 1 0)
         (odds (cdr list)))))
```

here is a tail recursive solution:

```
(define (odds list)
  (let odding ((list list) (count 0)))
    (if (null? list)
        count
        (odding (cdr list)
                (+ count (if (odd? (car list)) 1 0))))))
```

Here is a routine that counts anything based on a predicate:

```
(define (count-if predicate list)
  (if (null? list)
      0
      (+ (if (predicate (car list)) 1 0)
         (count-if predicate (cdr list)))))
```